# Convert CGImageRef to PIL

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library, cgimage, python-mss

How could I convert a CGImageRef to PIL without saving the image to disk on osx?

I though about getting the raw pixel data from the CGImageRef and using Image.fromstring() to make the PIL image by doing

```
import mss
import Quartz.CoreGraphics as CG
from PIL import Image

mss = mss.MSSMac()
for i, monitor in enumerate(mss.enum_display_monitors(0)):
    imageRef = mss.get_pixels(monitor)
    pixeldata = CG.CGDataProviderCopyData(CG.CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef))
    img = Image.fromstring("RGB", (monitor[b'width'], monitor[b'height']), pixeldata)
    img.show()
```

but this doesn't give me the correct image.

This is the image I expect:

[image]

and this is the image I get in PIL:

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a minimal yet complete and reproducible scenario for us to test? Perhaps you will get better answers if you do.

Comment: What does *does not give a correct image* mean, is it just random junk or does it look a bit like your image? If the latter you could at least submit the expected and actual image.

Comment: @Rachcha I updated the sample code that is being used

Comment: @AnttiHaapala its just junk, nothing like the image

Comment: I added what I expect to get and what the PIL image is

Answer (score 0):

The screencapture from CG doesn't necessarily use the RGB colorspace. It may use RGBA or something else. Try changing:

`img = Image.fromstring("RGB", (monitor[b'width'], monitor[b'height']), pixeldata)`

to

`img = Image.fromstring("RGBA", (monitor[b'width'], monitor[b'height']), pixeldata)`

Here is how I detect which colorspace is actually being captured:

```
bpp = CG.CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imageRef)
info = CG.CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef)
pixeldata = CG.CGDataProviderCopyData(CG.CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef))

img = None
if bpp == 32:
    alphaInfo = info & CG.kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask
    if alphaInfo == CG.kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst or alphaInfo == CG.kCGImageAlphaFirst or alphaInfo == CG.kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst:
        img = Image.fromstring("RGBA", (CG.CGImageGetWidth(imageRef), CG.CGImageGetHeight(imageRef)), pixeldata, "raw", "BGRA")
    else:
        img = Image.fromstring("RGBA", (CG.CGImageGetWidth(imageRef), CG.CGImageGetHeight(imageRef)), pixeldata)
elif bpp == 24:
    img = Image.fromstring("RGB", (CG.CGImageGetWidth(imageRef), CG.CGImageGetHeight(imageRef)), pixeldata)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug I fixed some time ago. Here is how to achieve what you want using the latest `mss` version (2.0.22):

```
from mss.darwin import MSS
from PIL import Image

with MSS() as mss:
    for monitor in mss.enum_display_monitors(0):
        pixeldata = mss.get_pixels(monitor)
        img = Image.frombytes('RGB', (mss.width, mss.height), pixeldata)
        img.show()
```

Note that `pixeldata` is just a reference to `mss.image`, you can use it directly.